# cout does no print in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, stdout, cout

I saw this question already on this forum but I do not know why the proposed answer does not work in my case. So I try to ask for other slution.

I just got my Qt creator running under Linux.

I do not understand why my:

```
cout << "This does not appear";
```

Does not print in console while qdebug does

```
qDebug() << "This appears";
```

This is what is contained in my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = aaa
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    IeplcModule.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    IeplcModule.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

#enable console
CONFIG += console
```

Any idea?

Comment: `cout << "This does not appear" << flush;` Maybe this one?

Comment: Does the output appear when the program stops? If yes, it's probably just a missing flush (add a std::endl)

Comment: Debug output is shown directly. The `<iostream>` equivalent of `qDebug()` is `cerr <<`, that doesn't need flushing either.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try with:

```
cout << "asdf" << endl;
```

Possibly Qt sets up iostream in order to flush only at new line.

Comment: +1 For the correct answer and explanation, by the way you didn't suggest using qDebug() as everyone did.

Comment: Actually, `endl` is a newline *plus* flush command. Similar to `"\n" << flush`

Answer (score 3):

When debugging with CDB (Windows debugger) and running application not in the dedicated terminal window, but within QtCreator output panel, there is an [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17265) with `std::cout/std::cerr`.
qDebug works because it has a trick for this case.
So, the only solution in this case is enable the "run in terminal" option.
For more infor please follow the link above to the Qt bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that STDOUT is redirecting? [qDebug prints to STDERR by default](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtglobal.html#qDebug).

Answer (score 1):

Did you `#include <iostream>`? I did not see any includes in the code.
I assume that `qdebug` and `cout` are very similar.

Comment: This question has already been solved by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `console` config enabled in your `.pro` file. I.e. :

```
CONFIG += console
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this program from CMD and it will print some messages to the console:

```cpp
/* Create a .pro file with this content:
QT += core gui widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
TARGET = app
-------------------------------
Build and run commands for CMD:
> qmake -makefile
> mingw32-make
> "release/app"
*/

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif

#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QIODevice>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

#include <iostream>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget()
    {
        setWindowTitle("My Title");
        QString path("assets/text.txt");
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "hello1" << std::endl;
        std::cout << path.toStdString() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "hello2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
    {
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    }
#endif

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```